# using breaks to traverse back multiple loops?

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab to read data from a serial port and have noticed that as the data is read many thousands of times (around 3500) it becomes out of sync for one or two samples. So I am trying to implement a way of ensuring the data is valid. Valid data consists of 4 values in descending order where no two values are the same.

below is the current code I have

```
 for x = 1:4 %loop for 4 values
    a(x) = fread(s); %reads 4 values of the data from the serial port and stores it to the matrix a
 end

 b = sort(a,'descend');

 if(b(1) ~= b(2) && b(2) ~= b(3) && b(3) ~= b(4)) %check each value is unique
    continue
 else
     break
 end
```

I know my implementation is incorrect except im unsure how to fix it. If the if statement isn't true then I want to sample 4 more values however my break currently just breaks out of the if statement when really I want some way to go back to the for loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if isequal(flip(a),unique(a))`. What do you mean "go back to the for loop"?  Do you want to read elements 1-4, then 5-8 then 9-12 etc? Can you read more than one value at each call to `fread`?

Answer (score 1):

Given the definition of valid data in your question,

> Valid data consists of 4 values in descending order where no two
>   values are the same.

you should not sort your data before checking that it's unique.
Instead of

```
b = sort(a,'descend');
if(b(1) ~= b(2) && b(2) ~= b(3) && b(3) ~= b(4))
```

you could simply do

```
if all(diff(a) < 0)
```

Another improvement would be skip the `continue` and do a `break` when the if statement fails.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
ready = false;
while ~ready
    for x = 1:4 %loop for 4 values
        a(x) = fread(s); %reads 4 values of the data from the serial port and stores it to the matrix a
    end
    b = sort(a,'descend');

    if(b(1) ~= b(2) && b(2) ~= b(3) && b(3) ~= b(4)) %check each value is unique
       ready=true;
    end
end
```

You can also replace the `ready=true` by a `break` statement, and make the while an infinite loop. `break` statements are meant to jump out of a *loop*, not a condition. Moreover, you only jump out one level.
The only two correct ways of doing this (that I can think of right now) is using either functions or loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have several problems, some of them are mentioned above:

1. Instead of your first loop try: `a = fread(s,4)` to get 4 values each time
2. Instead of your `if` use `diff(a)` like in @nilZ0r suggestion
3. Use a `while` loop to continue until there's an error

Here is a code for all that:

```
while true
a = fread(s,4);
if any(diff(a) > 0) 
    break
end
end
```

This is an infinite loop that will continue as long as the data is 'synced', but you may want to add another condition like reaching the end of the data.

Comment: @AmatuerCoder101, let me know if this answers your question, and it so please consider upvote/accepting it